# py2exe: How do I hide the console window for a service

Tags: python, py2exe

This is my setup.py

```
class Target:
  def __init__(self, **kw):
    self.__dict__.update(kw)

myservice = Target(
  description = 'My App',
  modules = ['main'],
  cmdline_style='pywin32',
)

setup(
  name = 'MyApp',
  service = [myservice],
  version = '0.1.0.0'
)
```

I know that there are many sources that explain how to hide the console on py2exe, but I haven't seen one that explains how to hide the console of a service.
When I run my app as a service then no console appears.
But when I run my app regularly by double clicking then it shows the console window.
I need the app to run both as a service and a normal process without a console window.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: I cannot use the windows option because it does not work with the service option, which is mandatory for my app

Answer (score 0):

py2exe doesn't provide a configuration flag to do it, but you can monkey patch it with these lines in setup.py:

```
from py2exe import build_exe
build_exe.py2exe.get_service_template = build_exe.py2exe.get_windows_template
```